# Layering of a HMI in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I ask for your help because I want to develop an interface for a chat (I'm training with Sockets etc .). The problem is (I'm getting mad with it), I know exactly what I want but I can't do it!

An image of what I expect :

[image: The theorical case]

I used different JPanel to implement the different views and after that I tried to mix it with a GridBagLayout.

The best I can obtain is this (I colored the header and the console panels) :

[image: In practice]

I implemented the different panels in different classes and I implement the main view in one class, so there is the mainView code :

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import com.awax.tchat.client.panels.Header;
import com.awax.tchat.client.panels.MessageBox;
import com.awax.tchat.client.panels.ServerBox;
import com.awax.tchat.client.panels.TchatBox;
import com.awax.tchat.client.panels.UsersBox;

public class TchatView extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected TchatModel tchatModel;
protected TchatController tchatController;

protected JMenuBar menuBar; // Barre des menus de la fenêtre
protected JMenu menuFichier; // Menu Fichier
protected JMenu menuAide; // Menu Aide

protected Header header; // Entête du tchat
protected MessageBox messageBox; // Boîte d'envoi des messages
protected ServerBox serverBox; // Boîte connexion au serveur
protected TchatBox tchatBox; // Affichage de la console
protected UsersBox usersBox; // Boîte d'affichage des utilisateurs connectés


public TchatView () {
    super("Tchat - v0.1 Alpha");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocation(200, 100);
    this.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 800));
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
 * Méthodes publiques
 */

// Permet d'initialiser les différents panels de l'interface
public void initView () {
    this.header = new Header();
    this.messageBox = new MessageBox(this.tchatModel, this.tchatController);
    this.serverBox = new ServerBox(this.tchatModel, this.tchatController);
    this.tchatBox = new TchatBox(this.tchatModel, this.tchatController);
    this.usersBox = new UsersBox(this.tchatModel, this.tchatController);

    setStyle();

    this.addWindowListener(new Window_Listener());
}

/*
 * Méthodes protégées
 */

// Permet de créer les éléments de la fenêtre
protected void setStyle () {
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    initMenuBar();

    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    gbc.weightx = 1.;
    gbc.weighty = 1.;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    this.add(this.header, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    this.add(this.tchatBox, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    this.add(this.serverBox, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    this.add(this.usersBox, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    this.add(this.messageBox, gbc);
}

// Permet de créer la barre des menus de la fenêtre
protected void initMenuBar () {
    JMenuItem item1, item2, item3, item4;

    this.menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    this.menuFichier = new JMenu("Fichier");
    this.menuAide = new JMenu("Aide");

    item1 = new JMenuItem("Item1");
    item2 = new JMenuItem("Item2");
    item3 = new JMenuItem("Item3");
    item4 = new JMenuItem("Item4");

    this.menuFichier.add(item1);
    this.menuFichier.add(item2);
    this.menuAide.add(item3);
    this.menuAide.add(item4);
    this.menuBar.add(this.menuFichier);
    this.menuBar.add(this.menuAide);

    this.setJMenuBar(this.menuBar);
}

/*
 * Listeners
 */

protected class Window_Listener implements WindowListener {
    @Override
    public void windowActivated (WindowEvent arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void windowClosed (WindowEvent arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void windowClosing (WindowEvent arg0) {
        tchatController.disconnectFromServer();
    }
    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated (WindowEvent arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified (WindowEvent arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void windowIconified (WindowEvent arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void windowOpened (WindowEvent arg0) {
    }
}

/*
 * Accesseurs
 */

public TchatModel getModel () {
    return tchatModel;
}

public void setModel (TchatModel tchatModel) {
    this.tchatModel = tchatModel;
}

public TchatController getController () {
    return tchatController;
}

public void setController (TchatController tchatController) {
    this.tchatController = tchatController;
}

}
```

Comment: everything depends of if and how could be resizable

Comment: I would be possible to resize the frame and maintain the placement of the different components :
- The server and users panels must stay at the top right corner
- The header and the messages panels must stay at the top and at the bottom of the frame
- And finally the console must occupie all the available space

So when I resize the frame it must respect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO The easiest and **most effective way of building Swing layouts is by using [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)**. This layout can easily replace any other layout available in JDK.

Here is the quick example, showing UI you're trying to build. *NOTE: The UI is resizable*

[image]

And here is the relevant code

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ChatPanel extends JPanel{
    public ChatPanel() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow][]", "[70px][grow][grow][50px]"));

        JLabel lbConsole = new JLabel("CONSOLE");
        lbConsole.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbConsole.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        JLabel lblMessageDialog = new JLabel("MESSAGE DIALOG");
        lblMessageDialog.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblMessageDialog.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        JLabel lblHeader = new JLabel("HEADER");
        lblHeader.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblHeader.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        JLabel lblServerInfos = new JLabel("SERVER INFOS");
        lblServerInfos.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        lblServerInfos.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblServerInfos.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        JLabel lblConnectedUsers = new JLabel("CONNECTED USERS");
        lblConnectedUsers.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        lblConnectedUsers.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblConnectedUsers.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        add(lblServerInfos, "cell 1 0 1 2,grow");
        add(lbConsole, "cell 0 1 1 2,grow");
        add(lblHeader, "cell 0 0,grow");
        add(lblConnectedUsers, "cell 1 2,grow");
        add(lblMessageDialog, "cell 0 3 2 1,grow");
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow ! Really efficient ! It's exactly that ! Thank you very much ;) I never heard about Miglayout so I will look more about this project :)

Answer (score 3):

- JComponents placed into JPanel returns by default own PreferredSize, then there no reason to set any Dimmension for childs JPanels
- JFrame (valid for all Top-Level Containers) has implemented in API BorderLayout (without gaps)
- JPanel has implemented FlowLayout, then accepting PreferredSize came from child, but Size for childs isn't resizable, stays uncchanged
- rest of JComponets haven't implemented any layout manager
- without sizing, put there JComponents, GUI will be showed properly without any additional setting for Size or Dimension (for example JTextField(10), JTextArea (10, 15) etc...),
- StandardLayout manager quite ignore setSize() ..., accepted only PreferredSize by default

edit/

in the case that you want to put only one JComponent to the container and this container will be accupied whole are, then to change LayoutManager (FlowLayout) JPanel to the BorderLayout and then to put JScrollPane to the BorderLayout.CENTER, size for JTextArea will be calculated from JTextArea(10, 15) e.i. sure to have to play with these number :-), for each of JPanels, there will be placed a lots of JComponents to the one JFrame together

/edit

for example,

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class NestedLayout {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel centerParent = new JPanel();
    private JPanel centerNorth = new JPanel();
    private JPanel centerCenter = new JPanel();
    private JPanel eastParent = new JPanel();
    private JPanel eastTop = new JPanel();
    private JPanel eastBottom = new JPanel();
    private JPanel southParent = new JPanel();

    public NestedLayout() {
        centerNorth.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        centerCenter.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        centerParent.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        centerParent.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        centerParent.add(centerNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        centerParent.add(centerCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        southParent.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        eastTop.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        eastBottom.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        eastParent.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        eastParent.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0, 5, 5));
        eastParent.add(eastTop);
        eastParent.add(eastBottom);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        frame.add(centerParent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(southParent, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(eastParent, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] a_args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                NestedLayout NL = new NestedLayout();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works well ! But the solution of Eugener is more effective and simplier, but thank you for your help ;)